# Using a variable named range in VBA code to copy the named range to another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, function, range, copy-paste

I have 2 sheets. Named "M" and "C". I have a table (named Test) in sheet "M" with multiple columns (named col1, col2 etc. etc. Each column is a named range. In sheet "C" I have a formula (cell "I2") to name the column I want to copy from sheet "M" to sheet "C". i.e., "Test[col2]" or "Test[col3]". My problem is i cannot get the VBS code to reference cell "I2" and copy the range from sheet "M" to sheet "C". I have tried assigning "I2" as a variable. Dim col range. Set col = "I2". then in the copy section of the code I try to use "col" to no avail.

[Table "Test"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzPSo.png)

[image: 1]

[=CONCATENATE(J2,I1,K2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0apEX.png)

[image: 2]

Comment: Please share the code (as text) you've got so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Copy an Excel Table Column

[image]

**VBA**

```vb
Sub CopyColumn()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("C")
    Dim srgReference As String: srgReference = CStr(dws.Range("I2").Value)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("M")

    Dim srg As Range:
    On Error Resume Next
        Set srg = sws.Range(srgReference)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If srg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "The reference """ & srgReference & """ is invalid.", _
            vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dCell As Range: Set dCell = dws.Range("I4") ' ???
    dCell.Resize(srg.Rows.Count).Value = srg.Value
    
End Sub
```

**Excel Formula**

- In Microsoft 365, a simple formula, e.g. in cell `I4`, will spill the result:

```
=INDIRECT(I2)
```

- The formula used in cell `I2`:

```
=J2&"[Col"&K2&"]"
```

Comment: Thanks, VBasic2008, that worked perfect. I just could not get it working... "srgReference as string" got me. Plus, you added as message box that I hadn't got around to yet. You get my vote.

Comment: Help again! Things changed a little bit and now I need to copy from a set column into a table range i.e., basically, just the opposite of what the first code did. Copy from a set column in worksheet C to a variable column in M.

Answer (score 0):

Explicit sheet object references improve clarity with multiple sheets.

```
Dim col Range

Set col = Sheets("M").Range(Sheets("C").Range("I2").Value)

' copying in a sheet
col.copy Sheets("M").Range("M2")

' copying to other sheet
col.copy Sheets("C").Range("M2")
```